# click items created by dynamic list and show dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a situation where I am generating a dynamic list. Now I am trying to click each item from the list and show some content for each. I understand I could use another array where I can store the content as divs and then point the location to show. Just cant figure out how to write it. here is what i have so far

```
<ul id="list">
<!--- List items will be added dynamically. --->
</ul>

$(InitPage);

    function InitPage() {

        var jList = $("#list");

        var arrValues = ['<div id="one"></div>', '<div id="two"></div>', '<div id="three"></div>'];

        $.each(
        arrValues,

        function (intIndex, objValue) {

            jList.append(
            $('<li class="thumbItem">' + objValue + "</li>"));
        });
    }

css--
li.thumbItem{
        float:left;
        width:192px;
        height:192px;
        background:gray;
        margin:10px 10px 0 0;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not use delegation?

```
$(function(){    
   $('#list').on('click','li',function(){
        //do stuff here
    });
});
```

For jquery 1.4, use .live():

```
$('#list li').live('click', function(){
            //do stuff here
        });
```

Comment: this could work but the problem is I have to use jquery 1.4.2...so basically when you click on each li items they should a coresponding content which might work.i tried this one...and it didnt..probably because the jquery version doesnt support it

$('.contentHolderContent').eq($(this).index()).show();

Comment: "because the jquery version doesnt support it"  Ya, true, .on() is supported on jquery 1.7+, use .live() instead. See my update.

Comment: dint not really work...this what i am doing
<!--this is where the generated list lives-->
generated list
<!--this is where the generated list lives-->
<!--contents to display on click-->
<div id="popupBox1"></div>
<div id="popupBox2"></div>
<div id="popupBox3"></div>

<!--click script-->

$('#contentHolder').children().attr('class', 'contentHolderContent');

 $('#list li').live('click', function(){
            $('li.thumbItem').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.contentHolderContent').eq($(this).index()).show();
        });